# JQuery галерея

Tags: jquery

Вот есть такая простенькая [ГАЛЕРЕЯ](http://truequery.ru/g_gallery_with_slip_effect_jquery/index.html)

При клике на следующую картинку, она прокручивается на нее.

Вот сам код прокрутки:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {

$("li").on("click", function(){

  var item = $(this),
      pos = "-"+(item.index() * 515)+"px";

  item.addClass("active");
  item.siblings().removeClass("active");

  $("ul").css("left", pos);

});

})();
  </script>
```

Прошу обратить внимания на то, как высчитывается позиция следующей картинки

```
pos = "-"+(item.index() * 515)+"px";
```

т.е. сдвиг картинки происходит на какую то константу.

Дело в том, что если у картин разная ширина, с картинка сильно сдвигается влево, иногда даже перекручивается.

Может как то нужно учитывать ширину следующей картинки?

Comment: Поместите код в jsfiddle.net

Comment: что то не получается, ошибки выдает сайт